# Update select tag dynamically with ajax in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have two dropdowns in a view, and I'm attempting to update the second dropdown options based on the selected value from the first dropdown.

I am aware of the Railscasts on this topic, but I do not want to use the grouped collections; The reasons for this are primarily that the user can select from one dropdown, or the other, and the results are filtered accordingly, the second dropdown **only** filters its options when a value from the first dropdown is selected.

My question is, how can I re-populate the select_tag options from a js.erb file?

**form**

```
  <%= form_tag("filter", :id => "filter_form", :method => "post") do %>
      <label for="company_id" class="company">Company</label><%= select_tag(:company_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all.order(:name), :id, :name), :prompt => "All Companies") %>
      <label for="product_id" class="product">Product</label><%= select_tag(:product_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Product.all.order(:name), :id, :name), :prompt => "All Products") %>
  <% end %>
```

**js.coffee**

```
  $('#company_id').change( ->
    sendFilterForm()
  )

sendFilterForm = ->
  $.get($('#filter_form').attr('action'), $('#filter_form').serialize(), 'script')
```

**controller**

```
@filterProducts = true
@products = Product.where(company_id: params[:company_id]).order(:name)
```

**js.erb**

```
<% if @filterProducts  %>
    $('#product_id').html(<%= options_from_collection_for_select(@products, :id, :name) %>);
<% end %>
```

So the last part is obviously quite wrong, but that is the concept of what I am trying to do. What is the proper way to accomplish this? I am open to rework this, if needed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a github repository with this? Maybe for Rails 4?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add `escape_javascript` to escape carrier returns, single and double quotes that get generated by `options_from_collection_for_select`.

I do not see any other problems except adding call to `escape_javascript`.  Please try the following in your **js.erb**:

```
<% if @filterProducts  %>
    $('#product_id').html("<%= escape_javascript options_from_collection_for_select(@products, :id, :name) %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow. How did I overlook that :-) Also needed to wrap the embedded ruby call in quotes within the html(). Thanks!

Comment: @Drew, Yes there you go, I've updated my answer adding quotes.

Comment: Do you have a github repository with this? Maybe for Rails 4?

Comment: j is also an alias for escape_javascript