# Dynamic dropdowns where to put the javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on dynamic dropdowns in rails and use this answer [Update select tag dynamically with ajax in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574462/update-select-tag-dynamically-with-ajax-in-rails) to guide me. However, so far I haven't worked with javascript in rails and I wonder in which files I should paste the respective code? Please see the link for reference.

"Form" code went to index.html.erb in my app

"js.coffee" code went to the coffee-script of my respective controller. My controller is called products_controller.rb so I created a script named products.js.coffee

"controller" code went into my controller called "products_controller.rb"

"js.erb" --> I dont know where to put it :(

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Rails Javascript Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html), but to give you a couple pointers.

Your "main" javascript file is `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

From here you can include other Javascript files through the `//= require <filename>` syntax.

You can use `.coffee` and `.erb` extensions freely for the javascript files you're loading.

There's a line in application.js which says `//= require_tree .`

This means that every file in the `app/assets/javascripts` will be automatically loaded.

So for example if you wanted to write a coffeescript file, you could create `app/assets/javascripts/my_file.js.coffee` and then in application.js write `//= require my_file`

If you needed ERB preprocessing you can rename the file to `my_file.js.coffee.erb` - the preprocessing steps are determined by the file extension chain.

Rails has files that appear to be controller-specific (`app/assets/javascripts/products.js.coffee`) but in reality all of these are compiled to application.js and are available on every page. See [here](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/) for more detail on this and instructions for how to get controller-specific Javascript, if that's something you need.